# r spatstat MinkowskiSum() returning multiple boundaries

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm trying to plot the Minkowski sum of a square and a rhombus.

```r
# a unit square
sq <- square(1)

# a rhombus
line1 <- psp(0,1,1,0,window=owin())
line2 <- psp(0,0,1,1,window=owin())
rhombus <- line1 %(+)% line2

# the Minkowski sum of the rhombus and the square
ply <- rhombus %(+)% sq
```

The `MinkowskiSum()` function (or the `%(+)%` operator) returns an object with attribute `$bdry` that contains 2 different sets of boundary points.

```r
ply$bdry # it has two sets of boundary points
```

After plotting it out, it seems like the first element in `ply$bdry` is the correct set of boundary points for `ply`.

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(ply, axes=TRUE, border="blue", lwd=2, hatch=TRUE, hatchargs=list(col="blue"))
plot(rhombus, add=TRUE, axes=TRUE, lwd=2, hatch=TRUE, hatchargs=list(texture=5))
plot(sq, add=TRUE, border="red", lwd=2)

plot(ply, axes=TRUE, border="white")
polygon(ply$bdry[[1]]$x, y = ply$bdry[[1]]$y, border="lightpink", col="lavenderblush") # this is the correct set of boundary points of the Minkowski sum
polygon(ply$bdry[[2]]$x, y = ply$bdry[[2]]$y, border="blue", col="lavender") # this is not the correct set of boundary points of the Minkowski sum
```

I've read through the manual and the source code but still couldn't figure out:

1. Why does MinkowskiSum() return multiple sets of boundaries and what does each set of boundary points correspond to?
2. How do I know which set of boundary points is the right one to use for plotting the resulting Minkowski sum?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to inspect the internal structure of the resulting object to decide how to plot it. Just use `plot` (which will be dispatched to `plot.owin`).

The result `ply` is a spatial window (object of class `"owin"`). Internally this is represented as a list with many components. One of the components is `$bdry` which gives the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon or polygons that represent the object. A spatial window may consist of multiple separate polygons, or polygons with holes; in these cases, `$bdry` is a list with one entry for each connected polygon representing a piece of the outer boundary or the boundary of a hole.

In your example, the result of the operation consists of two polygons. The first one is the one you would expect. The second one is a very tiny hole. You can see this using `print.owin` or `summary.owin`:

```
summary(ply)
Window: polygonal boundary
2 separate polygons (1 hole)
                 vertices         area relative.area
polygon 1               8  7.00000e+00      1.00e+00
polygon 2 (hole)        3 -9.75782e-19     -1.39e-19
enclosing rectangle: [0, 3] x [0, 3] units
Window area = 7 square units
```

The tiny hole is the result of numerical rounding error. Polygon calculations in `spatstat` are performed mainly using the `polyclip` package which works in integer arithmetic. Input polygons in continuous space are discretised to integer coordinates with a default resolution of `1e-09` units, using the midpoint of the surrounding rectangle as the origin. The `polyclip` calculation results in a hole of size about `1e-09` by `1e-09`. Use the `...` arguments to `MinkowskiSum` to change the discretisation.

Comment: Thanks Adrian! This makes sense. However, if I just use `plot(ply)`, it will also plot the "tiny hole" from `$bdry[[2]]`. In this example, this tiny hole is not that noticeable in the figure. But in my actual implementation of interest, I'm summing a bunch of line segments and the resulting Minkowski sum returned by `MinkowskiSum()` contains a lot of elements in `bdry`, and so directly doing `plot(ply)` does not give a very clean picture. Is there a way to resolve this without explicitly looking for which set of boundary points is the "effective" one? Thanks again.

Comment: If you know that the result should be a convex set (as in this case) then you could apply `convexhull` to the result, e.g. `ply2 <- convexhull(ply)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add slightly to the answer by @adrian-baddeley:
You can also use the information from `summary.owin()` to extract the boundary of the polygon with the largest area if you know that it should be the right result:

```r
s <- summary(ply)
ply2 <- owin(poly = ply$bdry[[which.max(s$areas)]])
```

Or you could keep any polygonal boundary that has absolute area above some threshold `eps`:

```r
eps <- 0.01
ply2 <- owin(poly = ply$bdry[which(abs(s$areas)>eps)])
```

(Here `abs()` is needed to keep holes of large negative area.)